# Apache : mysql and pdo_mysql : segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, apache, segmentation-fault

I am actually administrating a server, and my web-related applications are obviously having some problems...

When I look at my Apache error_log, I can see lots of... `[notice] child pid **** exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`.

After some search, enabling/disabling PHP modules, I found out that there might be a problem with the "mysql", or "pdo_mysql" PHP module.

- When mysql.so is enabled, but **not** pdo_mysql.so, no more segmentation faults occur. However, using mysql as a PDO driver in PHP applications is not longer possible.
- When pdo_mysql.so is enabled, but **not** mysql.so, child processes live longer, but still segfault after some time.

I've used gdb to explore some core dumps I've asked to Apache. There is the core dump analysis.

```
[New Thread 4565]
Reading symbols from /lib/libm.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libpcre.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpcre.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libselinux.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libselinux.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libcrypt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libcrypt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libexpat.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libexpat.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libdb-4.3.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libdb-4.3.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libdl.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libsepol.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libsepol.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libuuid.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libuuid.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libresolv.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libresolv.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_files.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libnss_dns.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnss_dns.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libldap-2.3.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/liblber-2.3.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/liblber-2.3.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libssl.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libssl.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libcrypto.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libcrypto.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/libcom_err.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libcom_err.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libkeyutils.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libkeyutils.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apr-util-1/apr_ldap-1.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apr-util-1/apr_ldap-1.so
Reading symbols from /lib/librt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_digest.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_auth_digest.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_alias.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_alias.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_anon.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_anon.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_dbm.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_default.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_host.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_user.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_owner.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_owner.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_dbm.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_default.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authz_default.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ldap.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_include.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_include.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_logio.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_logio.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_env.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_env.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ext_filter.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ext_filter.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mime_magic.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mime_magic.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_expires.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_expires.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_deflate.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_deflate.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_headers.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_usertrack.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_usertrack.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_setenvif.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mime.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_status.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_status.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_autoindex.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_info.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_info.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_fs.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dav_fs.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_negotiation.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_negotiation.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_dir.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_actions.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_actions.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_speling.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_speling.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_userdir.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_userdir.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_http.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cache.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cache.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_suexec.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_suexec.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_disk_cache.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_disk_cache.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_file_cache.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_file_cache.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mem_cache.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mem_cache.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_cgi.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_version.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_version.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/sse2/libgmp.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libnsl.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
Reading symbols from /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libdistcache.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libdistcache.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libnal.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libnal.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/curl.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libidn.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libidn.so.11
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/dom.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/dom.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/fileinfo.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/fileinfo.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/gd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/gd.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXau.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXau.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/imap.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/imap.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libc-client.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libc-client.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/libpam.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpam.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libaudit.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libaudit.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/json.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/json.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/mbstring.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/mbstring.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/mcrypt.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/mcrypt.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/mysqli.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/phar.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/snmp.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/snmp.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.10...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.10
Reading symbols from /lib/libwrap.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libwrap.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/soap.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/soap.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/wddx.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/wddx.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/xmlreader.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/xmlreader.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/xmlwriter.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/xmlwriter.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/xsl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/xsl.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libexslt.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libexslt.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libxslt.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so
Core was generated by `/usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb60e8dc6 in tcp_getline () from /usr/lib/libc-client.so.1
```

I am not very familiar with those analysis, but it seems like all my PHP modules are mentionned, none of them is missing. Doesn't seem to have any problem with mysql, nor pdo_mysql.

Having some experience in C programming, I would basically say that /usr/sbin/httpd requires more memory than he should. Perhaps I ask him to handle more modules than he's capable of. No idea. In this case, would there be a way to allocate more memory to the child processes ?

Or perhaps another problem I don't see ?
Thanks for you answers ;) If you need extra information, please ask.

---

Additional information :

PHP 5.3.3-13.el5_8 installed.
HTTPD 2.2.23-3 installed.
I don't have suphp installed, but I don't remember seeing it before upgrading to PHP5.3.
I have listed the modules requested by Apache (.ini files in /etc/php.d/), and each of them belongs to a php53-* package installed on my system.

Comment: make sure that your php modules, php itself, and the php module for apache are all compiled for each other. if you're mixing package sources/versions, there's no guarantees at all about how stable the setup will be.

Comment: I've recently updated to PHP 5.3, but I'm pretty sure the segfaults were here before. I've checked the versions, however could you tell me how you would do the checkings, so that I make sure everything has been done correctly ?

Comment: did you update the modules as well? using a module compiled for (say) 5.2 is not  good idea.

Comment: As you may know, the package name for PHP has changed from php to php53. Therefore, I had to remove them all, and install all the php53-* packages. Besides, yum doesn't find any php-* packages on my system anymore, only the php53-* ones. (updated my question with additionnal information)